# Get height of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, height

I wand to set the height of my `UITableViewCell` to the height, which I assign in the Storyboard.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell.frame.size.height;
}
```

With this code the App crashes.

Comment: Only use the [tag:xcode] tag for questions about the IDE itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to explicitly set the height.  Calling `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:` in `– tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` creates an infinite loop between the two methods.  It's a common first mistake with table views.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{

    return 64; // some value
}
```